# Using Index Match, while excluding a result from a previous use

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

So, I'm using an **Index** + **Match** formula to return an image on a specific cell, but I don't want it to return a duplicate from a previous use of the formula. I realize how unlikely this is with another **INDEX** + **MATCH**, as **MATCH** only returns a position so I can't realistically exclude the previous result there.

Example formula: `=INDEX(T2:U5,MATCH(B3:B10,T2:T5,0),2)`

Column **T** includes values to match the **B** column with, then it returns an image from the **U** column.

I want to do this twice, but exclude the first result the second time around. I'm fairly new to all these functions so I have no idea where to begin. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an actual image, or a link or some other text value for the image?  Also, can you provide a link to a sample sheet?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

I have since found a resolution to my problem. By first separating my target cells from the column with an index filter, then running match filter over those separated cells.